# I hope you find my email written in a formal way

Tags: sentence-structure

I do not know if the following structure grammatically correct.

> I hope you find my email written in a formal way.

or it should be written as follows:

> I hope you find my email was written in a formal way.

or

> I hope you find my songs written well.

The thing is here is that I would like to convey the sense that the email was written by me.

Comment: Idiomatically, we usually *find something **to be** [adjectival phrase]*. In some contexts we can omit that highlighted element (I suspect *I don't find this funny* is more likely than *I don't find this to be funny* in a conversational context), but this doesn't work very well in your specific context (which is obviously supposed to be "formal").

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I see. My problem is with more  the verb, to write,  following the noun : email in this case.   I can write another sentence :  I hope you find my songs written well. However , I still do not know if it is correct to say it.

Comment: Your example *I hope you find my songs written well* is technically valid, but would tend to sound awkward to a native speaker. Partly because it's more comon to say *I hope you find my songs well written*, but putting that aside, if you actually wanted to be "formal" you could say *I hope you find my songs **to be** well written*. If you just want to sound "conversationally natural", *I hope you [think/find] my songs **are** well written*.

Comment: What is the context of asking someone to assess whether your email was written formally? Are you asking a teacher or superior to check that you have used the correct tone in an email? If you are thinking of using this as a polite email sign-off, don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "show the email was written by me" then don't use the passive voice. The passive voice is useful to avoid showing who the email was written by.

So say

> I hope you will find that I have written my email formally.

However, there is something very odd about this wish.

It is odd to hope for something that is entirely within your control.  If you want your email to be found to be formal, then write it formally. You shouldn't ask for the person to find an informal email to be formal.

So the deeper answer is to avoid this sentence completely.

Comment: But that rewording transfers some emphasis from the product to the process, in my humble opinion.

Comment: That is intentional, as per the last line of the OP question.  However in fact this line shouldn't be used at all. I've added to the answer to state this.